# Row Level Security not applied in PowerBI Service

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, row-level-security

First of all, let me say that I am not a newbie. I have been working with power BI for several years.

Here is my problem: I have generated a report and created a rule in power bi desktop and published it on the power bi service. Everything is working fine, except for one user. No matter what I do with this user it keeps seeing all the data like if he is in the admin group, but he's not. I guess that he inherit authorization from a higher level that I can't see in power BI.

Do you know a way to debug this? Why is this user, with the same authorization level as is colleagues, is viewing all data?

Thank you so much for helping me resolve this mystery!

Comment: Check the roles (in which roles this user is a member) and workspace access.